# QGIS Web Client in Windows does not load map

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, windows, qgis-web-client

I have installed QGIS (1.8 Lisboa) desktop and server on a Windows XP machine. I am now trying to configure the QGIS Webclient. I downloaded the zip file from GitHUb, and made the changes to the templates, etc. When I open the qgiswebclient.html page the map does not load. The toolbars and other parts of the GUI are all there.

From OSgeo4w Shell I checked my mapserver is running: Mapserver v5.6.6

I copied the qgis-web-client folder into the osgeo4w\Apache\htdocs folder.

Does anyone know which parameters I should check?

Comment: For me the QGIS Web Client is working fine in Windows7. As the Script Alias changed from /cgi-bin/ "C:\OSGeo4W/bin/ to "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/" the php is not working now. Server returns the error message as below when typed localhost on address bar. "The requested URL /cgi-bin/php-cgi.exe/index.phtml was not found on this server" I need to add the login controls using php to the application but unfortunately I am stuck now. Please shed some light on this if some one resolved this.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS web client has nothing to do with Mapserver. It is a frontend for **QGIS SERVER**, so you need to install it with the osgeo4w installer.

The QGIS web client is not made to work on Windows server, so AFAIK there isn't a straightforward procedure to make it work. Anyway I found a way, but it isn't pretty:

- install QGIS Server and edit `https_qgis.conf` as described in the wiki.

  QGIS server is then accessible trough

  `localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe`
- edit `httpd.conf` and change

  `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:\OSGeo4W/bin/"`

  to

  `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/"`
- removed the ".exe" extension from `"qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe"` inside
  `"C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/"`

  At this point restart Apache and the server should work with this URL

  `localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi`

  if yes, you are good to go.

Comment: This works!  QGIS Web Client is running on Windows at last!  Runs faster under Linux though if you've got a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.... Im My case, the SRS code was differente in the GlobalOptions.js and my qgis projects....

so, i changed the EPSG variable in globaloptions to a srs code used in qgis project and the maps loaded...

Comment: Another sugestion... You can try change the EPSG parameter in the URL of the map, setting the qgis project srs code

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
useGetProjectSettings = true;
```

to

```
useGetProjectSettings = false;
```

in

```
js/GlobalOptions.js
```

This solved my issue that no map could be loaded. You need QGIS Server with a verison higher than 1.8 to be able to use this extension.